# Browsing through more than one tag on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, tags

I want to browse everything tagged with both **`[linux]`** and **`[performance]`** on Stack Overflow.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 20):

Use the search box in the top right of every page, with the following text:

```
[linux] [performance]
```

Encasing search tokens in square brackets causes the Stack Overflow search to treat them as tags.

You can also just follow one of these links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance%20linux
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance+linux

Answer (score 5):

Here an easier way:

- Click on a tag name to see all the questions with that tag. Now you're in "tagged view".
- In the "Related Tags" section in the right sidebar, you will see a list of related tags. Click on any of these tags to browse posts having both this tag and the original tag.
- You can click on more related tags to narrow down your listing to posts having all those tags

Comment: +1. This is such a cool feature.  It's what I call an attribute-driven search engine.  The attributes (or tags in this case) are shown for the current search results and can be clicked to further filter your results.  I've built similar search engines before, but I like the way StackOverflow does it so much that I've copied some of their ideas for my own site.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention this.  But the one benefit of browsing the site this way is that you can't reach a dead end (0 results).  And that, in my opinion, is what makes it a cool feature.